# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `alt` is marked as required in `MainImage`, but its value is `undefined`. MainImage

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

In my gatsby project I am getting this warning.

I am using Gatsby v3.

The warning looks like this

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `alt` is marked as required in `MainImage`, but its value is `undefined`.MainImage
```

The **index.js** looks like this.

```
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"

import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import * as style from "../styles/home.module.css"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

export default function Home({ data }) {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <Layout>
      <section className={style.header}>
        <div>
          <h2>Design</h2>
          <h3>Develop & deploy</h3>
          <p>Become web ninja</p>
          <Link to="/projects" className={style.btn}>
            My Portfolio Projects
          </Link>
        </div>
        <GatsbyImage image={data.file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} />
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query Banner {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "banner.png" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Please let me know why I am getting this warning ?

Also how can I use fluid image in gatsby v3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alt` `prop` in the new `<GatsbyImage>` component, from the `v3` of Gatsby, is required for accessibility improvements, so if you don't have it, just leave it empty but you need to provide it:

```
<GatsbyImage image={data.file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt={``} />
```

> Also how can I use fluid image in gatsby v3 ?

As you can see in the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/#fluid) and in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/), the `fluid` attribute has been renamed to `FULL_WIDTH` as a `layout` property, so to use it, the query should look like something like:

```
childImageSharp {
  gatsbyImageData(layout: FULL_WIDTH)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding image alt property, which cause warning in react

```
<GatsbyImage src="../images/dino.png" alt="A dinosaur" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First update your graphQl request to include alt (presuming you have alt):

```
childImageSharp {
  gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
  alt
}
```

Then update your markup

```
<GatsbyImage image={data.file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt={data.file.childImageSharp.alt}/>
```